# Why is the operator $P = - i \frac{d}{dx} $ not bounded in this domain?

Tags: operator-theory, self-adjoint-operators

the domain is:
$$D(P) = \{f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^2(\mathbb{R})\}$$
I think that is because some functions that belong to $D(P)$ should not be bounded at infinity.

The text I am studying suggests an example for bounded intervals, assuming that the domain of $P$, in this case, is:
$$D(P) = \{f \in C^{\infty}([a,b]) \cap L^2([a,b])\}$$
an example of the non-boundness of $P$ is represented by:
$f_n(x) = e^{-nx}$
in fact:
$$\frac{|| Pf_n(x)||}{||f_n||} = in \rightarrow \infty$$

Comment: Your $f_n$ is not in $L^2$ right? Unless you consider only $x>0$

Comment: Nope, in fact the example is valid for bounded intervals

Comment: Try to modify that example: it still work for $x>0$. Just cut it off in $\{x<0\}$

Comment: And your domain is wrong, you need also $f' \in L^2$.

Comment: Can i choose $f(x) = e^{-nx}$ if $x >0$ and 0 for $ x \leq 0 $ to prove that P is not bounded in the first D(P)?

Comment: Only that it is not smooth. You have to cut that off smoothly. This is usually done by a smooth cutoff function.

Comment: Can you show me an example of a function that shows the unboundness of P in D(P)?

Comment: I have provided..... cut off that $e^{-nx}$ with cut off function.

Comment: $f(x) = e^{nx}$ $x \leq 0 $ and $f(x)= e^{-nx}$ $x > 0$ is it ok?

Comment: Is your $f$ in the domain (is it smooth)?

Comment: @ArcticChar : His domain consists of functions on a finite closed interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: My understanding is that they are working on the domain $\mathbb R$, they bring up $[a, b]$ only for an example. @DisintegratingByParts

Comment: @Arctic Char you're right, i have to prove that on the domain $ \mathbb{R}$, P is not bounded. The text bring up only the closed interval example.